# 100 people in 20 rooms

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I have to put 100 people in 20 different rooms so that no room is empty and the president is alone in a room. Can I first from 100 people choose 1 to be the president and then from the remaining 99 people to choose 19 because they can't be in the room where the president is?

Comment: Presumably the president is already set (though you do need to choose a room for that person).  And, for the remaining $99$, you can't choose freely since that could leave some rooms empty.

Comment: Is it possible for me to use the x1+...+x19 = 99 for these other people, because I already placed the president in a room, and other 99 can't go there?

Comment: Sure.  Once the President has their room, the others must form a $19-$tuple of positive integers that sums to $99$.

Comment: So my final answer would be 100 over 1 times 19+99-1 over 19? I'm sorry for not using the preffered writing because I'm new to using this site.

Comment: I don't understand the $\binom {100}1$ term (guessing at your meaning here).  As I said, I assume the President is known before you start assigning rooms.  So there's a factor of $20$ for the President's room.  After that, you have a standard Stars and Bars problem.

Comment: Got it, thank you for the clarification!

Comment: This is unclear; are the non-presidential people considered distinct, or identical? If they are identical, then your $x_1+\dots+x_{19}=99$ idea works. If not, then you have to use Stirling numbers of the second kind, or PIE.

Comment: From where I read it, they didn't mention about people being distinct, so I assumed they are identical.

Comment: I don't remcommend using stars and bars here since people are inherently distinct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After assigning the president to his room ($20$ choices), we have to assign the remaining $99$ people to the remaining $19$ rooms so that no room is empty.

This is a PIE problem as Mike Earnest has pointed out.

Let $A_i$ be the set of arrangements in which the $i$th room is empty and $|A_i|$ be its size.

Then $$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_k|=(19-k)^{99}$$

By PIE, the number of arrangements in which at least one room is empty is given by

$$\sum_{k=1}^{19}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{19}{k}(19-k)^{99}$$

Thus the number of arrangements in which **NO** room is empty is:

$$19^{99}-\left [\sum_{k=1}^{19}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{19}{k}(19-k)^{99} \right]$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{19}(-1)^k\binom{19}{k}(19-k)^{99}$$

Thus the final answer is

$$20 \times \sum_{k=0}^{19}(-1)^k\binom{19}{k}(19-k)^{99}$$